# why do i hav to cast this in my Kotlin generic

Tags: generics, kotlin, interface

still trying to get the hang of generics in kotlin, i how can i write this to avoid the unchecked cast.

```
 class DBEntityUtil<T:DBEntity, S:Model> {
    fun entityListToModelList(entityList:List<T>): List<S>{
        val returnList:MutableList<S> = mutableListOf()
        entityList.forEach{entity:T ->
            returnList.add(entity.toModel() as S)
        }
        return returnList
    }
}
```

and the toModel()

```
interface IngestsModel {
    fun toModel(): Model
}
```

Comment: Edit the question and add the interfaces for `DBEntity` and `Model` please

Comment: As I understand your DBEntity is defined as `interface DBEntity {
    fun toModel(): Model
}`. Am I right?

Comment: `toModel()` could return any object belonging to the `Model` hierarchy. There's no way for the compiler, or the runtime, to check that it conforms to `S`.

Answer (score 3):

S is any subclass of `Model` and `toModel` can only guarantee to return a `Model`. If you want an `S` you have to cast. If you just want `Model` you can drop the generic `S` and should have no problem using `fun entityListToModelList(...): List<Model>`.

However if you want to make it work like shown you have to use a setup like

```
interface Model
interface DBEntity<S:Model> {
    fun toModel(): S
}
```

which ties the `DBEntity` to the type of `S`. That can be used like

```
class DBEntityUtil<S:Model, T:DBEntity<S>> {
    fun entityListToModelList(entityList:List<T>): List<S>{
        val returnList:MutableList<S> = mutableListOf()
        entityList.forEach{entity:T ->
            returnList.add(entity.toModel())
        }
        return returnList
    }
}
```

And used for example like

```
class TestModel: Model
class TestDbEntity : DBEntity<TestModel> {

    override fun toModel(): TestModel {
        return TestModel()
    }

    companion object {
        val util = DBEntityUtil<TestModel, TestDbEntity>()
        fun test() = util.entityListToModelList(listOf(TestDbEntity()))
    }
}
```

https://pl.kotl.in/Bkpc92vjm

Comment: Ty for the help....  I am slowly getting the knack of it... My java generics are not overly strong either....